# Vuex: referencing the modules variable inside action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have the following global store within my Vue application:

```
// N.B. These Stores Are Modularised, please reference: [https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html] for details.
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    surfers: surfers,
    surfSites: surfSites,
    surfTickets: surfTickets
  },
  actions: {
    resetAllState: ({ dispatch, modules }) => {
      console.log(modules); // Undefined
      console.log(store.modules); // Undefined
      console.log(this.modules); // Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: _this is undefined"
      for (const currentModule in modules) {
        console.log(`Resetting Module State: ${module}`);
        if (modules[currentModule].state.hasOwnProperty("initialState")) {
          dispatch("resetModuleState", currentModule);
        }
      }
    },
    resetModuleState: (currentModule) => {
      console.log(`Resetting Module State: ${currentModule}`);
    }
  }
});
```

My aim is that the actions will cycle through the modules, and dispatch off a reset state action, which I call when I log the current user out.

However, `modules` is undefined, `store.modules` and `this.modules` are all undefined or through an undefined related error...

So, how do I go about accessing modules dynamically in this way, if at all possible?

Comment: Modules aren't supposed to be accessed directly. Probably should be done by iterating over root state keys.

Comment: @Wind Up Lord Vexxos let me know if the below answer solves your issue

Comment: @chans Appreciate the answer but unfortunately, not. I get the same `Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: _this is undefined"`

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos, thanks for your response, we can solve your issue, let us know what error you are getting rightnow

Comment: @chans Thank you. See my reply below :)

Comment: @EstusFlask Thank you for the input, appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code is having issue, the actions can have only access to

```
{ commit, dispatch, getters } as params
```

but you tried to pass modules in the params, but still you can access to the modules by below approach

> use this code inside the action "resetAllState"

```
resetAllState: function ({ dispatch }) {
  for (const currentModule in modules) {
    this._modules.root.forEachChild((childModule) => {
      console.log(childModule);
    });
    //if (modules[currentModule].state.hasOwnProperty("initialState")) {
    //  dispatch("resetModuleState", currentModule);
    //}
  }
},
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the `Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: _this is undefined"`, removing your code removes the error in the console...

Comment: put console.log(this) and check the value inside this object,  you will have access to current store, in this way you have access to modules

Comment: `console.log(this) is `undefined`.

Comment: check the updated code in answer and try out, now see the console log message

Comment: replace arrow function with the normal javascript function