# How to handle multiple dispatches in nuxtServerInit using Axios

Tags: rest, vue.js, axios, vuex, nuxt.js

For some **context**: I am collecting data from my API using axios and adding it to the Vuex store in my Nuxt application using `nuxtServerInit`. I am using [name-spaced modules](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#modules-mode) as recommended in the docs to dispatch requests from my `index.js` file.

The **problem** is that while this *technically* works (everything is set in the store correctly), I end up with a long list of `await dispatch(...)` expressions in my `index.js` file. This does not seem to be a very efficient approach (or what the intended use is as I can't find a similar configuration in any of the docs) and I am wondering if I have misunderstood either the axios or nuxt documentation in my implementation. I have been looking into `Promise.all()` but cannot see how I would implement it here. Hopefully someone has some advice!

This is an example of the configuration I have arrived at with this approach:

`app/store/index.js`

```
export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit ({ commit, dispatch }) {
    await dispatch('endpointOne/storeDispatchInit')
    await dispatch('endpointTwo/storeDispatchInit')
    await dispatch('endpointThree/storeDispatchInit')
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

`app/store/endpointOne.js`

```
export const actions = {
  async storeDispatchInit ({ commit }) {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${this.$axios.defaults.baseURL}/endpoint-1`)
    commit('SET_ALL', data)
  }
}
```

I would also be quite happy to hear that this is the correct configuration after all...!

Comment: It's `return Promise.all(['endpointOne', /*...*/].map(ns => dispatch(ns + '/storeDispatchInit'))` instead of `await`s. Is there something more that troubles you here?

Comment: Hi @EstusFlask, thanks for the reply – I've tried this out but I get the error: `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","` so am unsure where I'm going wrong with that...? I guess my question is a bit more general as well, is this a common way to structure a `nuxtServerInit` request?

Comment: `)` is missing in my code, could be a problem. I don't use Nuxt much so can speak for Vue/Vuex in the first place. It seems that you could do storeDispatchInit for nested Vuex modules in parent module, something like shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60525082/vuex-referencing-the-modules-variable-inside-action . This way you would need only one dispatch in nuxtServerInit, seems cleaner to me.